# How do I get the attribute of an XmlElement as a double without creating a redundant class?

Tags: xml, vb.net, double

I have the following snippet of code:

```
<XmlElement("point")> _
                Public Property points() As List(Of Double)
                    Get
                        Return myPoints
                    End Get
                    Set(value As List(Of Double))
                        myPoints = value
                    End Set
                End Property
```

In reference to the following section of my XML document:

```
<upperLimit color="red">
                <point y="12"/>
                <point y="13"/>
                <point y="14"/>
                <point y="15"/>
                <point y="16"/>
            </upperLimit>
```

I am trying to tell my VB program that I want it to create a list of doubles from the list of "points" in my XML document. What I can't understand is how I can tell it to look at the `XmlElement` `point` and not take it's `innerText` but rather the `XmlAttribute` `y`

So something like this (i know this is wrong)

```
<XmlElement("point").XmlAttribute("y")> _ <-- Notice this line!!
                Public Property points() As List(Of Double)
                    Get
                        Return myPoints
                    End Get
                    Set(value As List(Of Double))
                        myPoints = value
                    End Set
                End Property
```

The only other alternative I see would be to create yet ANOTHER class to attribute the value to. I also can't even think of what to search on google to find an answer to this... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim xml As String = _
        "<upperLimit color=""red"">" & _
            "<point y=""12""/>" & _
            "<point y=""13""/>" & _
            "<point y=""14""/>" & _
            "<point y=""15""/>" & _
            "<point y=""16""/>" & _
        "</upperLimit>"

        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml)

        Dim results As List(Of Double) = doc.Descendants("point").Select(Function(x) Double.Parse(x.Attribute("y").Value)).ToList()
    End Sub

End Module
```